# How to apply `.mc/ini` file?

Tags: midnight-commander

I installed Midnight Commander and tried to change the colour scheme, but unfortunately, it doesn't apply the `~/.mc/ini` file.

It's Midnight Commander 4.8.1, on Ubuntu 12.04. When I installed it, it didn't have the `.mc` folder, so I had to create it first. I've searched the internet and found nothing useful.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 12):

The configuration is stored in

```
$HOME/.config/mc/
```

In your case edit the file `$HOME/.config/mc/ini`. You can check which files are actually read in by midnight-commander using `strace`:

```
strace -e trace=open -o mclog mc
```

Comment: There might be something else going on. If I edit `~/.config/mc/ini` before launching mc, change, say, `old_esc_mode=0` to 1, then launch mc, exit it, and check that file again - `old_esc_mode` will still be 0.

Comment: I can't seem to find th .ini file on CentOS.

Answer (score 3):

Try to edit settings before you launch mc itself, using nano or any other editor (but not the mcedit). 
Looks like mc saves current (at the launch time) setup settings each time you quit the file manager.

Comment: Hi welcome to SuperUser! Are you able to expand your answer with some evidence about when the software saves it's settings file?

Comment: This was my problem as well, I edited `.config/mc/ini` with mcedit, which didn't work because it would be overwritten by `mcedit`. Using `nano` worked.

Answer (score 1):

`mc`/`mcedit` has a config option called `auto_save_setup` which is enabled by default. This option automatically saves your current setup upon exiting. The problem occurs when you try to edit `~/.config/mc/ini` using `mcedit`. It will overwrite whatever changes you made upon exiting, so you must edit the `~/.config/mc/ini` using a different editor such as `nano`.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc (search for "Auto Save Setup")

Answer (score 0):

Did you use F9/Options/Save setup?

I'm asking because I had a similar problem (mc didn't save the panel sort order). It turns out that there's probably been some default settings change and now mc doesn't save changes to the configuration automatically anymore (that was the behaviour I was expecting...)

Answer (score 0):

Check folder owner for *~/.config/mc* folder. It should be same (your user) as others items in ~*/.config* has.

> ls ~/.config -l

If not - change owner to your's user. (via chown, or remove folder under root and create under your user)

Comment: My point was to suggest you [edit] and add this to your answer to make it complete.